# CSS3 Collapsible Panel

Tags: jquery, animation, css

I've been experimenting with the new webkit CSS3 animation techniques. I have made a collapsible panel that ought to work and yet strangely is jumping and being static.

CSS

```
.reveiws .content {
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:18px;
    height:72px;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
    vertical-align:top;
    max-width:560px;
    -webkit-transition: height 800ms;
    -moz-transition: height 800ms;
}
.reveiws .contentfull {
    height:100%;
    -webkit-transition: height 800ms;
    -moz-transition: height 800ms;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="pan<?php the_ID();?>" class="content"><?php the_content();?></div>

    <div class="author" style="text-align:left; padding-right:10px;">

    <a href="#" onclick="$('#pan<?php the_ID();?>').addClass('contentfull'); $(this).hide(); $(this).next().show(); return false">Read More &raquo;</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="$('#pan<?php the_ID();?>').removeClass('contentfull'); $('#pan<?php the_ID();?>').addClass('content'); $(this).hide(); $(this).prev().show(); return false" style="display:none;">&laquo; Close panel</a>
```

Heres a FIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/L6Jwa/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you have height of 72px in one class and 100% in another. Change to e.g. 400px in second class and it works fine.

I am not sure you can use % unit at all in such situation.

K